# Specifying custom weights for the nonparametric estimate of spatially-varying relative risk in spatstat

Tags: r, spatstat

Is there a way to specify weights in `relrisk.ppp` function in `spatstat` (version 1.63-3)?

The `relrisk.ppp` function calls the `density.ppp` function, which does allow users to specify their own weights.

For example, let us build upon the provided `spatstat.data::urkiola` data where, instead of individual trees, the locations are tree stands and we have a second numeric mark for the frequency of trees at each point-location:

```
urkiola_new <- spatstat.data::urkiola
urkiola_new$marks <- data.frame("type" = urkiola_new$marks, "freq" = rpois(urkiola_new$n, 3))

f1 <- spatstat::relrisk(urkiola_new, weights = urkiola_new$marks$freq)
```

When using the `urkiola_new` in a call of `relrisk`, `urkiola_new` is caught by `stopifnot(is.multitype(X))` in `relrisk.ppp`. I next tried specifying the weights separately as a vector while using the original `urkiola` data,

```
f2 <- spatstat::relrisk(urkiola, weights = urkiola_new$marks$freq)
```

but was caught by a warning from the `pixellate.ppp` function within the internal `density.ppp` function:

`Error in pixellate.ppp(x, ..., padzero = TRUE) : length(weights) == npoints(x) || length(weights) == 1 is not TRUE`

The same error occurs when I convert the weights into a list

```
urkiola_weights <- split(urkiola_new$marks$freq, urkiola_new$marks$type)

f3 <- spatstat::relrisk(urkiola, weights = urkiola_weights)
```

I suspect there is a way to specify the weights cleverly, but it yet escapes me. Any suggestions or guidance would be helpful, thank you!

Comment: Just a hint: do not use `$` to extract data from an object, and especially, do not use `$` to assign values to components of an object. This can corrupt the internal structure. For example, assigning `X$marks <- value` causes the internal structure of `X` to be corrupted. Use `marks(X) <- value` for this purpose.

Comment: @AdrianBaddeley Thank you for the essential tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `relrisk.ppp` is not currently designed to handle weights. The help entry for `relrisk.ppp` does not mention weights.

The example above does not work because `relrisk.ppp` applies `density.ppp` separately to the sub-patterns of points of each type, and the extra argument `weights` is the wrong length for these sub-patterns.

I will take this question as a feature request, to add this capability to `relrisk.ppp`. It should be done soon.

**Update**: this is now implemented in the development version, `spatstat 1.64-0.018` available at the [spatstat github repository](https://github.com/spatstat/spatstat)

Comment: Great news! I appreciate the quick response.

Comment: **Update**: this is implemented in the latest public release of `spatstat`, which is about to be published on CRAN as `spatstat 1.64-1`.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for adding this feature.